# How to show thumbnail on archive pages only?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

I have a Wordpress/Woocommerce website with a theme that displays a featured image thumbnail next to the post title using this code:

```
<?php 
    if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] ) && 
           $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' )
    { 
        woo_image( 'width=' . $settings['thumb_w'] . '&height=' . $settings['thumb_h'] . '&class=thumbnail ' . $settings['thumb_align'] ); 
    }
?>
```

However, I would like to display this thumbnail on archive pages only, not on the homepage. Is it possible to modify the code so it checks if the current page is the homepage, and, if it is, the thumbnail is not displayed?

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [WordPress Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). This Codex article explains how the content is displayed on a particular page depending on conditions.

Also, the question title contradicts the question description. Do you want the thumbnails on (a) archive pages only or on (b) all pages except the homepage?

While [jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556966/how-to-show-thumbnail-on-archive-pages-only#answer-30557074) has answered case (b), I'd like to expand that to answer case (a).

Check if you are on an archive page using [is_archive()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) and then display the thumbnail.

```
    if (is_archive()) {
        if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] ) && 
               $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' )
        { 
            woo_image( 'width=' . $settings['thumb_w'] . '&height=' . $settings['thumb_h'] . '&class=thumbnail ' . $settings['thumb_align'] ); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check the page url from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to display thumbnail if the the url matched desired pages see [function.preg-match.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

I assume we are talking WooCommerce / WordPress here.

In that case you can check whether you are on the home page using [`is_home()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home):

```
if (!is_home())
{
    if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] ) && 
           $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' )
    { 
        woo_image( 'width=' . $settings['thumb_w'] . '&height=' . $settings['thumb_h'] . '&class=thumbnail ' . $settings['thumb_align'] ); 
    }
}
```

You could of course combine all that, I have written it out for clarity.

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian Thanks for your help. It's working now. I tried    `if (!is_home ())` before but was getting an error because the syntax was incorrect.